# Full Calender hover on day change bgcolor

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

This is the code which i used for hover on day in full calender

```
function handlerIn(){
    $(this).css({'background-color':'#4d576c','color':'#fff'});
}
function handlerOut(){
    if($(this).hasClass('showAccordion')){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#4d576c','color':'#fff'});
    }else{
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff','color':'#000'});
    }       
}
$( '.fc-row td' ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

I have a problem while loading first this is proper. When we change month and this wont execute again. Can anyone help me in finding this.

Comment: Try `$(document).on('hover','.fc-row-td',handlerIn,handlerOut)`

Comment: You can also try https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ plugin here.

Comment: Its not working @GuruprasadRao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#4d576c','color':'#fff'});
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('showAccordion')){
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#4d576c','color':'#fff'});
    }else{
        $(this).css({'background-color':'#fff','color':'#000'});
    }   
    }
}, ".fc-row td");
```